# How do i get a cleartext representation of what protobuf-net serializes?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am trying to get a cleartext representation of what the protobuf looks like for debug purposes.
What I am looking for is a ".SerializeToText" that gives me a string with the protobuf data.
I would also think a ".DeSerializeToText" that takes a protobuf and just writes it out would work.
Does this exist or is there a good way to create one?

Regards
TeeCee

Comment: what it serializes is the data for the properties marked with the appropriate attribute.  not all of them are always string.  if you want to examine the output, save it to file and examine with a Hex Editor or similar

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid as I want to include the data into verbose logging for the test-team as a convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is a seconday format in protobuf that is string-based, however it has never been implemented for protobuf-net, as frankly it loses all the advantages of protobuf. If you want a string representation, your best bet is to use "json.net" or "jil" to write the object model as json.

Comment: Thank you. This was the information i was looking for. I understand youre point and agree but would it not be useful for debugging/logging purposes as long as the implementation of what to serialize and into what corrolate between the two outputs?

Comment: @TerCee that depends: who is designing, implementing, testing, deploying and supporting it? :)

Comment: @Mark i know what you mean and i think you have done a super job with proto-net :)